# How to use calculus to find the equation of a parabola that is tangent to a quartic

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am stuck on this homework question:

Use calculus to find the equation for a parabola in the form $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ with an $x-$intercept at $(2, 0)$ if it is tangent to the curve $y = (x^2 - 4x)^2$ at $x = 1$.

The answer is $y = -21x^2 + 54x - 24$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: many of us want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: @Rory Daulton I've tried to find the derivative of the quartic then take the derivative of the resulting cubic but that didn't work and I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Why would you want the second derivative of the quartic? You need for the derivatives of the two curves to be equal at $x=1$.

Comment: Have you drawn a graph of the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two equations:

$y = ax^2 + bx + c\\
y = x^4  - 8x^2 + 16$

And you must solve for $a,b,c$ such that the two curves coincide at the same point when $x = 1$
$y(1) = y(1)\\
a+b+c = 9$

Have the same slope at that point

$y'(1) = y'(1)\\
2a + b = ??$

and for the parabola

$y(2) = 0\\
4a + 2b + c = 0$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

You need three pieces of information to find the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

First, you know that the parabola goes through the point $(2,0)$. Second, you know that the parabola goes through the same point that the other curve does at $x=1$. Third, you know that the parabola has the same slope that the other curve does at $x=1$.

Use each datum to find an equation in $a$, $b$, and $c$. Then solve those simultaneous equations.

Comment: Im not sure how to use the fact that they have the same slope at x = 1